# Just took new job and unhappy

Tags: professionalism, new-job, new-hires

I have only been in my current position for a few weeks. Before this, I worked for one company for over 8 years. My current position is not panning out how I had hoped. There really isn't much room for growth, and it isn't nearly challenging enough. I had the thought in my first week, "A trained monkey could do this." Is it okay for me to start looking for a different position already? Yes, I know I should/could give it longer. I just don't see myself being any happier 6 months down the road. Wouldn't it be better to leave earlier rather than later?

If I do decide to find another job, do I still list this one on my resume? It isn't outside of my normal industry.

Comment: Have you spoken to your manager about possibly getting more responsibility?

Comment: I'm in your position as a new graduate/worker... I will have spent 6 months with this company, but that's 3 months too long. I know how you feel getting no challenge or growth...

Comment: It won't hurt you to search for another job as long as you stay in your current job until you get an offer.  If prospective companies reject you because they think you're flighty, as long as you have a job, you aren't any worse off.  Furthermore, you can afford to be picky so that your next job really is a job you want to stick at for a while.

Comment: This will probably be closed as a duplicate, but I just wanted to say I feel your pain :( I went through a similar situation just over a year ago. It hurts when a new job you've pinned your hopes on turns out to be abysmal - but you'll find something better.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should have a conversation with your hiring manager. It's quite possible as you are just starting out that it will take the company some time to transition you from a new person with little ability to participate actively into someone knowledgeable about the company and able to take on larger roles.

However, if what you are doing is not going to be what you were led to expect or if you aren't able to find out when some "real work" will be coming down the pipeline then you may need to move on. You should be able to find a way to request some more responsibility, workload or whatever and see if it's going to be available without getting into a conversation that puts you in a position of being let go before you can find the next position.

In any case, sometimes these things don't work out. The company might still have the ability to call up their second choice for the position if not too much time passes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might want to find whether your dislike of the new place is because of the cultural differences or the work related. If it is the former case, then you might want to give some more time to adjust with the new environment. You know the exact reasons. If you are sure that you are unable to enjoy the work and sure that there will be no growth at the current place, then you can start looking to move to other companies. Since you have already proved that you are loyal to a company by working 8 years, it is fine to move to another place. If your stint with the current company is just less than a few weeks, I think that it is fine to remove that history from your resume.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid to move on.  Find a better job, life is too short and it sounds pretty clear this isn't for you.

If asked down the road or when interviewing, just be candid.  Tell them you rushed into this job and it wasn't the job you thought it was.

I have held numerous jobs and could be characterized as a job hopper even, and never been questioned on it.